# Why doesn't guard execute?

Tags: swift3

I have the following:

```
guard let _ = myfunction() else {
  print("guard just executed")
  return false
}
```

`myfunction` returns false but the code within the guard isn't executed. Isn't that the correct scenario in which the guard should execute?

The function is defined as:

```
func myfunction() -> Bool?
```

but returns only true or false (not optionals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`guard let` is used to wrapped the optional value so that in your case `guard let _ = myfunction() else {` always return true, if you want to also check(compare) its value you need to add one more condition with `guard` statement separated by `,`  like this way.

```
guard let flag = myfunction(), flag else {
    print("guard just executed")
    return false
}
```

Comment: If I'm returning non optional booleans, guard isn't really needed?

Comment: @4thSpace Yes exactly mate :)

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the `guard case let` suggestion.

Comment: @LeoDabus: Thanks but if there is only one condition, I guess `guard case let` has no advantage over a simple `if` conditional?

Comment: Back to the same question: What advantage is guard in that case?

Comment: @4thSpace In your specific question guard condition else return has no advantage over if NOT condition return.

Comment: @LeoDabus: Cool. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

`let _ = myfunction()` evaluates to `true` if the result of `myfunction()` is not nil regardless of whether it returned `Int?`, `String?`, `Bool?`, etc.    If the result is not nil, it does not matter whether the unwrapped `Bool?` value is `true` or `false` in the same way it would not matter if the unwrapped value of an `Int?` was 5, 37 or 2089.

`guard let _ = myfunction() else {}` falls into the guard condition only if the result of `myfunction` is nil.

Answer (score 1):

`guard let` requires an optional argument, if you need only to check a boolean result there is a simpler syntax

```
guard myfunction() else { ...
```